# Configure mobile accounts in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to configure mobile account for Sharepoint 2013, the issue I have is that the sms service runs on Http not Https. Do I still need to import the root certificate of the service provider? Will SharePoint work will http sms services

Any feedback will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is requirement you have to build trust with sms gateway.you can't build a trust without certs

you must import the root certificate of the service provider's HTTPS web address, and then create a trusted root authority.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428323.aspx